# WiFi Driver Issues ASUS_PCE-AC88

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, broadcom

**Update: I've decided to return the card as there doesn't seem to be any linux firmware support to date.**

I can't get my Wifi card (ASUS_PCE-AC88) to work on Ubuntu 16.04 The card does not show up in the network manager.

I've created this question specifically because I haven't found any good information on ubuntu drivers for `[14e4:43c3]` yet.
The thread on askubuntu about broadcom drivers ([Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395)) does not list my version.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

I've already tried installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` and loading the module wl via `sudo modprobe wl` which resulted in an error on boot:

```
ERROR @wl_cfg80211_detach : NULL ndev->ieee80211ptr, unable to deref
```

I'm running the following kernel version: `4.4.0-72-generic`

Info on the chip:

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited Device [14e4:43c3] 
(rev 04)

lshw -class network
*-network UNCLAIMED  
   Beschreibung: Network controller
   Produkt: Broadcom Limited
   Hersteller: Broadcom Limited
   Physische ID: 0
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
   Version: 04
   Breite: 64 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   Konfiguration: latency=0
   Ressourcen: memory:feaf8000-feafffff memory:fe000000-fe7fffff 
memory:fb800000-fbbfffff
```

More info on the card:
https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_PCE-AC88

**Update:**

```
dmesg | grep brcm
[   13.868848] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   14.001095] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for 
brcm/brcmfmac4366b-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[   16.403501] brcmf_pcie_download_fw_nvram: FW failed to initialize
```

Running `sudo modprobe -r wl` and `sudo modprobe brcmfmac` did not print anything to the console. (Wifi card is still `UNCLAIMED` and does not appear in network manager.)

**Update 2**

```
modinfo brcmfmac | grep firmware
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4354-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4339-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43362-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4335-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4334-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4330-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4329-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43143-sdio.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43569.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43242a.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43236b.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43143.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4371-pcie.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4371-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4366b-pcie.txt    
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4366b-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4365b-pcie.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4365b-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4358-pcie.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4358-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43570-pcie.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
parm:           fcmode:mode of firmware signalled flow control (int)
```

Comment: Please open a terminal and do: `sudo modprobe -r wl` and next: `sudo modprobe brcmfmac` Finally, let's gather some diagnostics: `dmesg | grep brcm` Please edit your question to add the result of the final command.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you. I've updated the question as requested.

Comment: @pbz Hi can you please test to see if the Special Case in https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395 will also help you. I just tested 2 ASUS PCE-AC88 AC3100 and it is working correctly. One on 17.04 and another in 17.10. Let me know friend.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but support for this card is now in the latest version of Ubuntu.

I just installed Ubuntu **server** 19.04 and the card worked out of the box.

**Beware** it did not work at all with the new installer which crashes on boot and I could not get to work, so use the alternative installer instead.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the Wikidevi page that you linked, the correct driver for your device is *brcmfmac*; not the proprietary driver *wl* provided by bcmwl-kernel-source. In *dmesg*, it shows that the driver loaded but the required firmware wasn't found.

I believe that the latest version of *linux-firmware* has the needed file. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tether or whatever means possible, please open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.164_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and let us see:

```
dmesg | grep brcm
```

Comment: I've installed the package and rebooted. `dmesg | grep brcm` still has the same output as before.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `modinfo brcmfmac | grep firmware` My version of the driver doesn't call for any *txt* files; only *bin*.

Comment: May we also see the result of: `sudo mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars`And then: `ls  /sys/firmware/efi/efivars`

Comment: sudo mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
mount: mount point /sys/firmware/efi/efivars does not exist

Comment: How about the second command?

Comment: My system does not support efi, it's a legacy bios,  thus the directory does not exist, I assume.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57508/discussion-between-chili555-and-pbz).